# Symfony2 data transformer string to entity (reverseTransform)

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I am pretty new to Symfony and hope someone can help me. I have an entity called Material and an associated entity called MaterialKeyword, which are basically tags. I am displaying the keywords comma delimited as a string in a text field on a form. I created a data transformer to do that. Pulling the keywords from the database and displaying them is no problem, but I have a problem with the reversTransform function when I want to submit existing or new keywords to the database.

Material class (MaterialKeyword):

```
/**
 * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Entity\MaterialKeyword")
 * @Assert\Valid()
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MaterialKeyword", inversedBy="material")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="materials_keyword_map",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="materialID", referencedColumnName="materialID", nullable=false)},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="keywordID", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)})
 */
public $materialkeyword;


/**
* Constructor
*/
public function __construct()
{
    $this->MaterialKeyword = new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Set materialkeyword
 *
 * @param array $materialkeyword
 *
 */
public function setMaterialkeyword(MaterialKeyword $materialkeyword=null)
{
    $this->materialkeyword = $materialkeyword;
}


/**
 * Get materialkeyword
 *
 * @Assert\Type("\array")
 * @return array
 */
public function getMaterialkeyword()
{
    return $this->materialkeyword;
}
```

Here is my code from the data transformer:

This part is working:

```
class MaterialKeywordTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $manager;


    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms an object (materialkeyword) to a string.
     *
     * @param  MaterialKeyword|null $materialkeyword
     * @return string
     */
    public function transform($material)
    {
        $result = array();
        if (null === $material) {
            return '';
        }

        foreach ($material as $materialkeyword) {

            $result[] = $materialkeyword->getKeyword();
        }

        return implode(", ", $result);

    }
```

This part is not working:

```
/**
 * Transforms a string (keyword) to an object (materialkeyword).
 *
 * @param  string $materialkeyword
 * @return MaterialKeyword|null
 * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (materialkeyword) is not found.
 */
public function reverseTransform($keywords)
{
     // no keyword? It's optional, so that's ok
    if (!$keywords) {
        return;
    }

    $repository = $this->manager
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:MaterialKeyword');


    $keyword_array = explode(", ", $keywords);

    foreach($keyword_array as $keyword){

        $materialkeyword = new MaterialKeyword();
        $keyword_entry = $repository->findBy(array('keyword' => $keyword));

        if(array_key_exists(0, $keyword_entry)){
            $keyword_entry_first = $keyword_entry[0];
        }else{
            $keyword_entry_first = $keyword_entry;
        }

        if (null === $keyword_entry_first) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf('There is no "%s" exists',
                $keywords
            ));
        }
        $materialkeyword->setKeyword($keyword_entry_first);

    }


    return $materialkeyword;

}
```

There will be several keywords, so how do I store them. I tried Arrays and ArrayCollections (new ArrayCollection()) without any success.

The error that I am getting currently with the code above:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /.../vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 605 and defined
```

Comment: Can we see `Material` code? Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: I added the MaterialKeyword code. I don't think you need all of the Material class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Hanzi put me on the correct track. It has to be an array of `MaterialKeywords` objects.

Here is my final working code in class MaterialKeywordTransformer:

```
    /**
     * Transforms a string (keyword) to an object (materialkeyword).
     *
     * @param  string $materialkeyword
     * @return MaterialKeyword|null
     * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (materialkeyword) is not found.
     */
    public function reverseTransform($keywords)
    {
         // keyword are optional, so that's ok
        if (!$keywords) {
            return;
        }

        $repository = $this->manager
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:MaterialKeyword');

        $repository_m = $this->manager
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Material');

        $keyword_array = explode(", ", $keywords);

        foreach($keyword_array as $keyword){

            $materialkeyword = new MaterialKeyword();
            $materialkeyword->setKeyword($keyword);

            if($this->opt["data"]->getMaterialID() !== null) {
                $materialkeyword->setMaterialID($this->opt["data"]->getMaterialID());
            } else {
                $material = $repository_m->findOne();
                $materialID = $material[0]->getMaterialID();
                $materialkeyword->setMaterialID($materialID);
            }

            $materialkeywords[] = $materialkeyword;

            if (null === $keywords) {
                throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf('There is no "%s" exists',
                    $keywords
                ));
            }

        }       

        return $materialkeywords;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you're telling I assume that `Material` and `MaterialKeyword` are connected by a ManyToMany association, in which case each `Material` has an **array** of `MaterialKeyword` objects associated to it.

Which means, that your Data Transformer should work with arrays as well, but you're only working with single objects.

Specifically, `reverseTransform` should return an array of `MaterialKeyword` objects, whereas you're only returning one (the last one handled in the loop.)

Another issue is that your method created new objects every time, even though `$repository->findBy(...)` would already return a `MaterialKeyword` instance. Creating a new object would cause that entry to be *copied* instead of simply used.

So the correct method might look like this:

```
public function reverseTransform($keywords)
{
    // no keyword? It's optional, so that's ok
    if (!$keywords) {
        return array();
    }

    $repository = $this->manager
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:MaterialKeyword');

    $keyword_array = explode(", ", $keywords);
    $result_list = array(); // This will contain the MaterialKeyword objects
    foreach($keyword_array as $keyword){
        $keyword_entry = $repository->findOneBy(array('keyword' => $keyword));

        if (null === $keyword_entry) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf('There is no "%s" exists',
                $keyword
            ));
        }

        $result_list[] = $keyword_entry;
    }

    return $result_list;
}
```

Comment: The case where `!$keywords === true` should return an empty array and not null IMO. Doctrine ArrayCollection will not like to instanciate with null as a ctor argument: https://github.com/doctrine/collections/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php#L36

Comment: I tried your code, but without luck. Getting error: Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\MaterialKeyword", "array" given

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR;
Your `reverseTransform` function should return an array containing zero or n `MaterialKeyword`.

It should not return a single `MaterialKeyword` object because the reverse transformation of `MaterialKeyord[] --> string` is not `string --> MaterialKeyword`, it is `string --> MaterialKeyword[]`.

Thinking about this, the doctrine ArrayCollection exception you have make sense as it is trying to do `new ArrayCollection(/** Single MaterialKeyword object */)` instead of `new ArrayCollection(/** Array of MaterialKeyword objects */)`.

Comment: Is adding $result = new ArrayCollection(); and returning $result with an MaterialKeyword objects array correct? Because it fails with error 'Expected argument of type "AppBundle\Entity\MaterialKeyword", "array" given'

Comment: @Gildas.how can i do that, do you have an example ?